# How to extend the client area of NSWindow?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nswindow

That's the way it's called in Windows, sorry if I use different term. I want to make a window that looks like that:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In code:

Modify the window's style mask with `setStyleMask:` including `NSTexturedBackgroundWindowMask` in there (look for "Window Style Mask" constants in the docs for other constant that can go in the style mask). If you are creating a new window, use `initWithContentRect:styleMask:backing:defer:` similarly.

In Interface Builder:

Select the window you want, go to the fourth tab from the left in the inspector and check the "Textured" checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

Apple calls that a textured window.  You can enable that in Interface Builder or specify NSTexturedBackgroundWindowMask in the window's style mask.